# Django rendering template variables containing HTML as plaintext, but the source has styling

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm having an odd issue with Django 2.0.4 (which maybe isn't so odd since I'm new to it).

I have a template which I am rendering from a view, and the data passed in is a string containing HTML.

My view renders the template as so:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', { 'data' : data })
```

data.content contains HTML in the above.

In my template, I am rendering it as so:

template.html (what works):

```
{{ data.content|safe }}
```

This renders fine. However when I have this template include other templates, the HTML ceases to render correctly.

template.html (what I want):

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

{{ data.content|safe }}

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

The above renders header.html and footer.html fine, but the data.content|safe part in between actually becomes text with no styling. If I view source it's correct HTML (real tags, classes, etc. No & l t ; funny business.), but the browser doesn't apply rendering to it. It just winds up plaintext, e.g. strong tags around a word don't make it bold, lists are just linebreaks, etc. Even though the HTML in the top and bottom templates are included correctly with displayable HTML.

The oddest part is the only HTML that is rendered correctly from that variable is hrefs. Nothing else. I think it's crazy that no other tag works. There is no CSS messing with the HTML, either.

I have also tried using {% autoescape off %} ... {% endautoescape %} with the same results.

Obviously my intention here is to have my view display an HTML page composed of multiple templates, with values distributed among them. Yet I can't even get this **one** variable to display correctly, let alone any others.

Thank you so much for any help.

Edit:

header.html:

```
{% load static %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta name="Description" content="" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,600,600i,700|Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Roboto:300,400,400i,700|Arvo:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "org/css/foundation.min.css" %}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "org/css/styles.css" %}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
```

template.html:

{{ data.content|safe }}

'data.content' is the string '`<strong>test</strong>`'

footer.html:

```
  </body>
</html>
```

The resulting view source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta name="Description" content="" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,600,600i,700|Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Roboto:300,400,400i,700|Arvo:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/org/css/foundation.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/org/css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <strong>test</strong>

    </body>
  </html>
```

The resulting displayed HTML page is just 'test' with no strong styling.

Comment: What is in your header/footer? Are you sure that there isn't an unclosed tag in the header that is breaking everything that comes after it?

Comment: header.html and footer.html do not contain any malformed HTML.As I said, footer.html renders perfectly, and I assume that wouldn't be the case if header.html was malformed.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you then - it's highly likely the issue is to do with what you're rendering as opposed to the broad template structure which should work just fine.

Comment: You might get a better answer after posting the actual contents of `header.html`, `footer.html`, and the resulting HTML source.